# How to add JavaScript to a SharePoint Team Site List

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, list-view, jslink

I have a team site and would like to add JavaScript to influence the list's appearance.

I have Custom Scripts enabled, but the "Form Web Parts" Ribbon option is grayed out and the JSLink Property outlined [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd) wasn't in the properties list in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS Link is not supported in modern listviews (which I'm assuming you're using since you tagged your question with sharepoint-online).

The simplest way to customize field appearance is to use [Column Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting). I wrote a webpart to make this even simpler: [PnP Column Formatter](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/ColumnFormatter).

If you want to use JavaScript you'll need to use a [SharePoint Framework Field Customizer (SPFx Extension)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions).

There's a helpful guide if you're already familiar with JS Link here: [Migrating JSLink customizations to SharePoint Framework Field Customizers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-jslink-to-spfx-extensions)

Comment: I'm new to working on SP, so I do not have past experience with JSLink. Is SPFx the recommended path forward?

Comment: Yes, in fact it's the only way to customize modern pages/sites. Classic pages still require traditional approaches.